# Long URL's on the developer story traditional view run into other page elements

Tags: bug

I noticed a small design issue today. When I go to the developer story on my user profile and select the 'Traditional' view, the URL I have entered into the 'website' field runs into the icon of the next column.

[image: Image of issue]